# read events from facebook page with graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Normally I can go view the calendar events on the Facebook page in question by going to `https://www.facebook.com/pg/somepage/events/`. Now I am trying to get the events using the graph api. Any advice on how to fetch those events?

It appears I need a token. But when I go to `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2` it asks me to "Paste in an existing access token or click 'get user access token'". So since I don't have an existing access token, I tried to go through the get user access token path. But that process seems to be about my own profile as opposed to the third party I am trying to access.

I am extremely new to the graph api and I am trying to make sense of it by reading their doc. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the API call to get events of a Page:

- https://graph.facebook.com/somepage/events?access_token=xxx

For an unrestricted Page, you can just use an App Access Token without any authorization. If the Page is restricted by age or location, you need to use a User or Page Access Token. Just use your own App to get the Token, the Graph API Explorer App is just for testing.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

**Update: Getting Events is not possible anymore, at least for now:**

> This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/

Comment: Is there any source for this? Because I can't find it on your links and it doesn't seem to work any more. My page is public with no restrictions, events are all public, yet when I use the App access token I get back an empty array of events - If I use a user access token it works, but this is for my web page, it's server to server.

Comment: It's a shame what they have done to their API - hopefully it all gets fixed soon.